# Google plus login getIdToken returns null

Tags: android, authentication

I'm trying to integrate google plus login in my app. But when i call getServerAuthCode() and getIdToken() it always returns null. I can't figure out what is the exact issue is.

```
     private void handleSignInResult (GoogleSignInResult result)
     {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {

            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), acct.getDisplayName() + "-" + acct.getEmail() + "-" + acct.getServerAuthCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "Server Token google" + acct.getServerAuthCode() + "-ID token" + acct.getIdToken());
            create_account_method(acct.getEmail(), acct.getDisplayName(), acct.getServerAuthCode());

        } else {

        }
    }
```

Comment: think your using  Plus.API, recommend using Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API and follow @Jemo Mgebrishvili solution.

Answer (score 8):

Probably you already solved but for future reference. I was having the same problem and the solution was in fact very simple.

After reading the getIdToken documentation in this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount) i figured out that it was missing the requestIdToken(serverClientId) and the .requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId, false) call when I was building the GoogleSignInOptions object.

Here is the code:

```
String serverClientId = getResources().getString(R.string.google_server_client_id);

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
                .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestIdToken(serverClientId)
                .requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId, false)
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you initialize it correctly?
try this

```
onResume() {
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestProfile()
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME))
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}
```

after clicking login button

```
public void gmailLogin(GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient) {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I have already initialized it but still getting null, when i call getServerAuthCode() and getIdToken()